# C++ reference variable across files

Tags: c++, variables

I have a project where I need to reference a variable declared in one CPP file in another, is that possible?

If so, how?

Comment: It is possible using `extern` keyword as stated in the answers, but maybe you could provide why you need it. Global variables are discouraged, so a better solution could exist.

Comment: Yup, in many cases, global variables do more harm than good... like wondering where the hell this variable comes from when you read it a few weeks later

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible, if you declare it as global (top-level, above any function definition) and use "extern  ;" in other files to make it known to the compiler.

```
// Main.cpp
#include <...>

int myNum;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   // MAGIC BE HERE
   return 0;
}
```

and

```
// Second.cpp
#include <...>

extern int myNum;

int f()
{
   return myNum * 2;
}
```

`extern` prevents the compiler from allocating memory again when a variable was allocated in another file.

Answer (score 3):

Create a .h file declaring the variable you need as `extern` (something like `extern int X;`), then include it in any file that need that variable. In one of the .cpp files you're linking, declare it without the `extern`.

Comment: Wasn't it the other way around?