# How do I access a variable in a one C file from another?

Tags: c, file, variables

I have two C files. I want to declare a variable in one, then be able to access it from another C file. My definition of the *example* string might not be perfect, but you get the idea.

```
//file1.c

char *hello="hello";
```

---

```
//file2.c

printf("%s",hello);
```

Comment: The answers are the same as for this C++ question [1]. I prefer putting the `extern` declaration in a header file rather than just repeating the declaration all over. [1] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080439/c-reference-variable-across-files

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
// file1.h
#ifndef FILE1_H
#define FILE1_H
extern char* hello;

#endif


// file1.c
// as before


// file2.c
#include "file1.h"
// the rest as before
```

Answer (score 4):

`*hello` in `file1.c` must be *declarated global* and `extern` in `file2.c` must be *global* too (not inside *function*)

```
//file2.c
extern char *hello;

... function()
{
printf(...)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have would work.  What you want to research is "linkage" in C.  Basically objects not within a function or marked as static are extern (think global).  What you need to do in this case is notify the compiler that there is in fact a variable called hello defined elsewhere.  You do this by adding the following line to file2.c

```
extern char* hello;
```

Answer (score 2):

this works

t.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    extern int d;

    printf("%d" "\n", d);
    return 0;
}
```

h.c

```
int d = 1;
```

output

```
[guest@localhost tests]$ .ansi t.c h.c -o t
[guest@localhost tests]$ ./t
1
[guest@localhost ~]$ alias .ansi
alias .ansi='cc -ansi -pedantic -Wall'
[guest@localhost ~]$
```

Answer (score 2):

file1.c

```
int temp1=25;
int main()
{
.
. 
}
```

file2.c

```
 extern int temp1;
 func1();
 func2(temp1);
```

`temp1` is defined in `file1.c`  .when you want to use it in `file2.c` you must write 
extern int `temp1`;
you must do it in each file which you want to use this variable

Answer (score 0):

### file_2.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int count;
void extern_function();

void main()
{
count = 5;
extern_function();

}
```

### file_3.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

void extern_function()
{

extern int count;   
printf("the value from the external file is %d",count);

}
```

### Now run the code

```
    $gcc file_2.c file_3.c -o test
    $./test
```

It works!!